# Implementing sets in $\lambda$-calculus

Tags: set-theory, foundations, lambda-calculus, formal-systems

Both Set theory and $\lambda$-calculus are considered to be valid foundations for mathematics. Since these are both *equivalent* (in the sense that any structure that can be implemented in set theory can be implemented in $\lambda$-calculus, and vice-versa), is there a way to implement sets in $\lambda$-calculus?

Comment: If any structure that can be implemented by sets can be implemented by $\lambda$-calculus, then trivially sets can be also implemented in $\lambda$-calculus, because they can certainly implement the notion of a set...

Comment: Right, that argument makes sense. However, is there an explicit way to do this? (for instance, there is an explicit way to encode ordered pairs in both set theory and lambda calculus)

Comment: You may be interested in Aczel's type-theoretic interpretation of CZF, although it could not be related to your question.

Comment: I don’t know exactly what you’re referring to by “lambda calculus” but [this paper](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~awodey/preprints/stcsFinal.pdf) by Steve Awodey may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to inform you that the lambda calculus [(Church, 1932)](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F1968337) as a foundation of mathematics was shown to be logically inconsistent [(Kleene and Rosser, 1935)](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F1968646). Therefore your question is moot.

Comment: I think it's a bit more complicated than that, depending on how generously we interpret "lambda calculus". (Certainly it can't be Church's original untyped lambda calculus.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen This is a math forum, not a philosophy forum where words might be subject to interpretation. I don't know of any other lambda calculus than the one by Church. Of course, there are various typed lambda calculi, but this would be a different question.

Comment: Lol at the notion that words aren’t subject to interpretation in math. Also that you don’t know of any lambda calculus other than the one by Church but also know of various typed lambda calculi. Not trying to get into a protracted stupid argument here, but couldn’t let that go. Also, no intention of downvoting your answer as I think it’s a reasonable interpretation (!) of the question.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there a version of untyped lambda calculus that is not inconsistent? (similar to how the ZFC formulation of Set theory avoids Russell's paradox and does not rely on the notion of types)

Comment: @Art The only way I know of to avoid Curry's paradox (simpler than the Kleene-Rosser paradox, but still lethal) is to move to a typed lambda calculus.

Comment: @Art - In my opinion, your question is not only "moot" (as Dave says in his correct [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3797689/288417)), but it starts from the wrong premise that the $\lambda$-calculus is one of the "valid foundations for mathematics". This failure does not mean that the $\lambda$-calculus is useless, because it (or better, just its portion relevant to computation, see [Church, 1936](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F2371045)) is a handy and universal model of computation that can be used to simulate any Turing machine. But this is another story.

Answer (score -2):

Sets can be implemented as lists in $\lambda$-calculus. The order of the elements in the list can be ignored by allowing only one type of function on the list - a membership test. All lists that produce the same results on performing membership tests are equivalent.

Comment: Can anyone point out if there's a mistake in this approach? Something doesn't feel right, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: How would you define the set of all real numbers or any other uncountable set? Anyway, your answer sounds like an other question.

Comment: This is far from be an implementation of sets. You'll need to define what a set is (in terms of lambdas) and prove that those sets satisfy the axioms (and axiom schemas) of ZFC (or at least ZF).

Comment: Okay, thank you for pointing out the flaws.